# Forward request from compute engine (GCP) to on-premise API

Tags: networking, google-cloud-platform, google-compute-engine, portforwarding

I'm trying to forward requests from a compute engine instance to an internal API (its an on-premise API that communicates to the VM through `Cloud VPN`) but without luck, I tried to research how to accomplish this, but with no results.

Someone knows how to achieve it?. In short my goal is to *access the on-premise API from my local computer for development purpose* using the CE as a proxy.

I am open to create more resources or to change the CE instance if there its a better way to handling this.

My VM is a simple Debian 10 machine.

Comment: Is there a network path from your CE to your on-premises server hosting the API?  Are there firewalls blocking incoming requests at the on-premises server?  What have you tried and what has been the outcome?  You said you tried something "without luck".  What did you try and what did you find?

Comment: A common method is SSH tunneling using the Compute Engine instances as the middle man. Google search as there are many good examples how to do this.

Comment: I didnt know that could be an option. Do my research and finally can connect to the CE from my local computer which serve me to access the on-premise API (which has no firewall whatsoever). 

You can accomplish this by following this tutorial: https://cloud.google.com/community/tutorials/ssh-tunnel-on-gce

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As John Hanley commented. You can accomplish this by doing SSH tunneling using the CE instance as the middle man.

A good tutorial to follow is [this](https://cloud.google.com/community/tutorials/ssh-tunnel-on-gce) one, which is from the GCP community itself.